# Security Concerns on clientside(Javascript)

Tags: appsec, web-application, javascript, client-side

We are going to design and implement a UI for a big website. Owner of the site is really cautious about security issues. I wonder if there is a check list for security issues at the client-side ,while designing and coding in Javascript.

Comment: What is the client protecting? What data is available via the website? What identification and authentication are you using, if any?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There will never be a single perfect checklist, but here's a few things worth going through:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security) doesn't do half bad on this one
- More for AJAX or other rich interfaces, but worth a read depending on your architecture - [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ajax_and_Other_%22Rich%22_Interface_Technologies)
- This seems worth a test drive - haven't tried it myself - [Javascript sandbox](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_JavaScript_Sandboxes#tab=Project_Details)

Yes, none of these is a true "checklist" - IMO what you need to look for in Javascript vulnerabilities has a lot to do with how you are using it and what the rest of your architecture looks like - so I'm not sure a checklist will really cover the real concerns.  It may be better to go through a risk analysis first, and then see how that translates into how you use the various web technologies as a collective.

Comment: An additional step of value would be to perform validation of the developed environment. This could be performed in-house by an off-the-shelf application vulnerability scanner or by an independent third party. This should be done before the site goes live in production.

Comment: @lour - great point!  Thank you!  Didn't even think of that (smacks self in head).

Comment: @ lour- what do you mean by developed environment?

Comment: @saeed, the validation should occur after development has finished. There is little value validating the product /before/ development has finished, as it is still subject to change.

Comment: "OWASP JavaScript Sandboxes is a Javascript sandbox which converts code using regular expressions." - hmmm.

Answer (score 3):

To properly secure a web application, you need to have a good idea of how browsers and servers work. Javascript is only the tip of the iceberg.

For an introductory (but thorough) review of web application security, I recommend Michal Zalewski's [The Tangled Web](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/tangled/). The book comes with checklists (called "security engineering cheat sheets") at the end of each chapter.